# Не получается заменить весь текст файла на свой

Tags: bat, txt

Мне нужна ваша помощь, чтобы вы подробно показали как заменить текст в файле.

Я думал что найду сайт, возьму код оттуда и спокойно начну дальше кодить, но нет, каждый код для перезаписи строки или замены текста не работал. Так как это делалось в батнике, те командной строке то ошибок я не знаю, батник просто вылетал и не говорил ничего.

Пробовал дописывать сделанный ранее код заново, но уже основываясь на коде с сайта но написав уже по своемому. Тоже не получилось

нет кода. я его оставил в папке которая чиститься приложением, и он смылся пока я делал другие дела по ПК

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Говорю намного точнее. Нужно сделать так, чтобы батник заменил строки текстового файла на мои строки. Тоесть я напишу в переменную свою строку, и потом он эту строку напишет в текст файл. Использовать copy a.txt + b.txt a.txt, мне не нужно. Нужно без лишних файлов

Comment: А тебе прям обязательно `cmd` надо? Какой-нить powershell не пойдёт?

Comment: батник такого не умеет (без упомянутых костылей с copy).  поэтому создай программу на бейсике (script.vbs), которая делает нужную замену строки, и запусти её из своего bat-файла